# spark-sql-streaming-mqtt bad user or password

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, mqtt, paho

I am trying to consume mqtt as a stream in apache spark the lib used is apache bahir spark-sql-streaming-mqtt.
This library use paho mqtt library.

I'm using the lib as follows :

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder
  .appName("MQTTStreamWordCount")
  .master("local[4]")
  .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._
// Create DataFrame representing the stream of input lines from connection to mqtt server
val lines = spark.readStream
  .format("org.apache.bahir.sql.streaming.mqtt.MQTTStreamSourceProvider")
  .option("clientId", "sparkTest")
  .option("username", "user")
  .option("password", "psw")
  .option("brokerUrl", "tcp://ip:1883")
  .option("topic", "/bikes")
  .option("cleanSession", "true")
  .load("tcp://ip:1883").as[(String, Timestamp)]

  val query = lines.select("value").writeStream
  .outputMode("append")
  .format("console")
  .start()



query.awaitTermination()
```

And i get this error: "bad username or password".

But in another akka/scala project I use paho-mqtt lib on the same broker, with the same user/psw and it work fine.

so i'm confused with this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution :

1. Use paho-mqtt lib version 1.1.0 to have autoReconnect method :

   "org.eclipse.paho" % "org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3" % "1.1.0"
2. build your own bahir spark-sql-streaming-mqtt from github source because authentication isn't present on existing release.
   https://github.com/apache/bahir